# How Do I Make Ansible Retry on SSH Errors?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I am occasionally getting SSH failures in my Ansible 2.6.19 playbook during operations that that use `file` or `copy` with large `with_items`. Several items will succeed then at some point I will get

```
Shared connection to xxx.xyz.com closed
sudo: PAM account management error: Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info
```

Then 2 seconds later there is a `SUCCESS` message for each of the rest of the files. This suggests to me that something must have happened on the server to cause the issue and then it resolved itself.

I have `pipelining = True` in my `ansible.cfg`.

How do I make Ansible playbook try again on SSH errors like this so the playbook doesn't fail?

**EDIT:** To address the comment, I am investigating the source but since I don't have control of it I need a backup. The retry/until is at the task level, however, there are too many tasks to put it on each one. I really need something at a playbook level. e.g. in `ansible.cfg`

Comment: Since you did not mention it, I suspect you did not try the basic [retry/until](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) which should IMO work (i.e. `until: my_copy_result is success`). Meanwhile, I strongly suggest your rather try to find the cause of those intermittent connection outage and fix them directly at the source.

Comment: Run Ansible once again. This is the idea of Ansible. You can run it as often as you want, because it is [idempotent](https://www.packetcoders.io/what-is-idempotency/).

Comment: If it is an overnight job and the only issue is a brief blip in the server auth service, it is a waste of time to come in the next day and run it again if ansible could just try the connection again on the first run.

Answer (score 0):

One option at configuration level is use [retry files](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#retry-files-enabled). This will allow you to rerun the playbooks with the `--limit @path/to/retry-file` option.

Excerpt from `ansible.cfg`:

```
retry_files_enabled = True
retry_files_save_path = ~/.ansible-retry
```

This will cause a `<playbook>.retry` file to be created (in `~/.ansible-retry/` directory) when a playbook failure occurs. Though it doesn't make Ansible automatically retry, the playbook can be rerun with `--limit` option to cover the hosts on which failure occurred. This can be combined with error handling (as @Zeitounator commented).

The other option is to use the [wait_for_connection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_connection_module.html) module.

```yaml
- name: wait for connection to host for 2 mins
  wait_for_connection:
    timeout: 120
```